# Issues playing radio stream with the MediaPlayer

Tags: android, stream, buffer, android-mediaplayer

We developed a radio streaming application. The app uses a `MediaPlayer` instance in a service to play the radios in background. Every radio works fine, but we're having an issue with some radios. For example:

```
player = new MediaPlayer();
...
player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
player.setDataSource("http://108.166.161.217:8615/metro.mp3");
...
player.reset();
player.prepareAsync();
player.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
   @Override
   public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
      mp.start();
   }
});
```

For now [this](http://108.166.161.217:8615/metro.mp3) is the only radio where we have troubles. All the radios load very fast, but this one takes like 15~20 seconds to load, then works, then pauses by another 15 seconds and then plays just fine. This is the only one that we found so far, but for sure there's more.

We are searching some kind of way to configurate the `MediaPlayer` so we can avoid changing the whole `MediaPlayer` by some library.

**UPDATE:**
This is another case http://7309.live.streamtheworld.com/VEGARETRO_SC

**UPDATE:**
Apparently, may have something to do with [this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=29870) issue. Searching some workaround.

Comment: As I can see, the radio service of this particular radio is very busy and that's the problem - in the developer console of Chrome I see the following message `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Too many clients connected)` So can't you disable this radio? Is it so important to be in your app?

Comment: @GabriellaAngelava Sorry, [this](http://7309.live.streamtheworld.com/VEGARETRO_SC)  is another case. I'm gonna edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

Using [this](https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaPlayer) library everything was fixed, I really recommend it!